MariaDB is rolling back (removing rows) when running LOAD DATA INFILE on large CSV files
I have large CSV files with stock values and I have successfully added these to my MariaDB database using the "LOAD DATA INFILE" command:
LOAD DATA LOCAL
INFILE '/mnt/HD/HD_b2/Public2/raw_data/DEUIDXEUR_01.csv'
INTO TABLE raw_data_index_germany_at_eur
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY ';'
(timestamp_, bid_price_, ask_price_, bid_volume_, ask_volume_);

This works just fine for data files with around 3-4GB of data but any bigger and the query will start removing the X million rows that it just added and leave me with an empty table.
The csv's syntax:
2024-08-13 16:52:24.857|439.935|441.292|0.0120000001043081|0.0179999992251396;
2024-08-13 16:53:28.445|439.911|441.003|0.0120000001043081|0.0120000001043081;
2024-08-13 16:54:03.299|438.87|440.836|0.0120000001043081|0.0120000001043081;
2024-08-13 16:56:18.582|438.602|439.68|0.0120000001043081|0.0120000001043081;
2024-08-13 16:56:21.290|438.747|439.636|0.0120000001043081|0.0120000001043081;
2024-08-13 16:56:40.607|438.891|440.83|0.0120000001043081|0.0120000001043081;
2024-08-13 16:57:02.280|438.985|440.927|0.0120000001043081|0.0120000001043081;
2024-08-13 16:57:10.698|438.917|440.853|0.0120000001043081|0.0120000001043081;
2024-08-13 16:58:33.543|439.011|440.95|0.0120000001043081|0.0120000001043081;
2024-08-13 16:58:45.200|439.165|441.128|0.0120000001043081|0.0120000001043081;
2024-08-13 16:59:01.138|439.367|441.13|0.0120000001043081|0.0120000001043081;

What am I missing? If the buffer size is the culprit, shouldn't MariaDB take care of the import and do it in chunks? Or should I somehow address this prior to the query?
Table engine is InnoDB btw.
EDIT:
Here's the output from CREATE TABLE raw_data_index_germany_at_eur :
CREATE TABLE `raw_data_index_germany_at_eur` (
  `id_` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp_` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(3) ON UPDATE current_timestamp(3),
  `bid_price_` decimal(32,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ask_price_` decimal(32,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bid_volume_` decimal(20,14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ask_volume_` decimal(20,14) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_` (`id_`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci COMMENT='TABLE_TYPE=index\r\nTABLE_EXCHANGE_ITEM=germany\r\nTABLE_EXCHANGE_CURRENCY=eur\r\nDATA_FILE=DEUIDXEUR.csv\r\nDB_DIRECTORY=/mnt/HD/HD_b2/Public2/db' DATA DIRECTORY='/mnt/HD/HD_b2/Public2/db/'

EDIT2:
I tried this command (to reset the serial) and I see that the disk where the database settings is stored are full... but the disk where the table is stored isn't on that disk. How do I make sure that MariaDB dump the temp file onto the correct disk during the import?
MariaDB [daydreamer]> ALTER TABLE daydreamer.raw_data_index_germany_at_eur AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ERROR 3 (HY000): Error writing file './daydreamer/#sql-alter-624e-152.frm' (Errcode: 28 "No space left on device")

EDIT3:
root@WDPR4100 mnt # df -i
Filesystem              Inodes      Used Available Use% Mounted on
mdev                    486079       253    485826   0% /dev
/dev/loop0                9047      9047         0 100% /usr/local/modules
/dev/mmcblk0p6            5136        97      5039   2% /usr/local/tmp_wdnas_config
tmpfs                        0         0         0   0% /mnt
tmpfs                        0         0         0   0% /var/log
tmpfs                    20000       106     19894   1% /tmp
/dev/md0p1               35200        10     35190   0% /usr/local/upload
/dev/sda4               258048        17    258031   0% /mnt/HD_a4
/dev/sdb4               258048       156    257892   0% /mnt/HD_b4
/dev/sdc4               258048        17    258031   0% /mnt/HD_c4
/dev/sdd4               258048        17    258031   0% /mnt/HD_d4
/dev/md1             121831424    623292 121208132   1% /mnt/HD/HD_a2
/dev/md2             121831424        57 121831367   0% /mnt/HD/HD_b2


please edit your question to show output of show create table raw_data_index_germany_at_eur.  seems most likely to me it is failing on some bad data; if you broke the file up into smaller chunks were you able to process all of it?

The size of data shouldn't matter, by default  the file will be sent from client in chunks of 8K blocks. Please provide more information: 1) Error message/return code  from LOAD DATA statement 2) Error logs from server.

Okay, I added some more information. @GeorgRichter

Do not use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE. Drop the LOCAL, use LOAD DATA INFILE, and make files readable by the server process.

Please don't ask multiple questions. It's obvious that the data directory runs out of diskspace which is the cause of your problems.
